# Find In Progress Order in Main Table & Sub Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Edited sorry I made some mistake in the questions**

I have a main and sub table.

The Main Table as below

```
 order_id    | status
-------------+-------------
 12345       | In Progress
 88862       | In Progress
```

The Sub Table as below

```
 main_order_id    | order_id    | status
------------------+-------------+-------------
 12345            | 54x         | In Progress
 12345            | 54d         | In Progress
 88862            | 32x         | Complete
 88862            | 32d         | In Progress
```

I want the result to display only order_id 12345 by combining the main table and sub table using the status.

Comment: Is the goal to find every record in the main table having the same status in the sub table for all records?  Or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have update the question, i make some mistake in the question, is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you want to eliminate any `main_order_id` from `sub_table` in the final output where any row has status other than 'In Progress'. You can use `not exists` to eliminate them. So something like:

```
with main_table (order_id, status ) as 
     (values (12345, 'In Progress')
           , (88862, 'In Progress')
     ) 
   , sub_table (main_table_order_id, order_id, status) as   
     (values (12345, '54x', 'In Progress')
           , (12345, '54d', 'In Progress')
           , (88862, '32x', 'Complete')
           , (88862, '32d', 'In Progress') 
      )
-- your query starts here
select s1.*
  from main_table  m
  join sub_table   s1 
    on (    s1.main_table_order_id = m.order_id 
        and s1.status = m.status
       ) 
 where m.status = 'In Progress'
   and not exists (select null 
                     from sub_table s2
                    where s2.main_table_order_id = s1.main_table_order_id 
                      and s2.status <> 'In Progress'
                  );
```

NOTE: Be very careful  using the same column name in related tables where the column represents a completely different data point. In this case `main_table.order_id` and `sub_table.order_id` are different, but will everybody understand that, especially when issues arise.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'order_id ' || order_id  from main_table a 
where a.order_id in
        (select main_order_id from sub_table where status='In Progress')
and a.status='In Progress';
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is currently written - it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, from the logical perspective.
I can not understand the actual use case for that need, and you might be missing something in the explanation or what exactly you are trying to achieve, but here what you should do to get what you asked for:

> I want the result to display only order_id 12345 by combining the
> main table and sub table using the status"

```
select * from main_table, sub_table 
where  main_table.order_id = 12345
and    main_table.order_id = sub_table.order_id
and    main_table.status = sub_table.status
```

Note that this kind of query in actual systems required having proper indexing on the table.

Comment: Why don’t you write a join as a join?

Comment: I do not have postgress to check the exact syntax in postgress of join, this does the same and agnostic to the db it is being executed on

Comment: Well, just standard SQL, JOIN.